# Will GNOME 3.38 ever be in the official Ubuntu 20.04 repositories?

Tags: gnome, package-management

I know that GNOME 3.38 is a flagship feature of Ubuntu 20.10, but will we be able to install 3.38 on 20.04 so we don't have to give up the LTS status?

Comment: Related: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/816190)

Comment: These are two different questions. Because you accepted an answer that does not address the question in the title of your post, I will edit the title to only refer to the question that was actually answered.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No.

LTS releases are intended to be *stable* in the sense that the software does not change. The software on 20.04, with limited exceptions, won't be updated. That's the whole point of an LTS.

- LTS releases continue to receive security updates from the Ubuntu Security Team, and major bugfixes. These security updates include newer versions of web browsers. However, a whole new desktop stack is neither.

Let's take a look at an example: The Gnome environment from 18.04...

```
gnome-shell | 3.28.1-0ubuntu2                   | bionic
gnome-shell | 3.28.3+git20190124-0ubuntu18.04.2 | bionic-security 
gnome-shell | 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3             | bionic-updates
gnome-shell | 3.36.1-5ubuntu1                   | focal
```

...see how gnome-shell 3.28 was in Ubuntu 18.04? You can see the minor updates from security patches and bugfixes, but *it's still on version 3.28*. Meanwhile, 20.04 uses Gnome 3.36. And two years from now, it's likely to still be using 3.36.

In general, if you want newer software, you should run a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Therefore, the advice to always have an update like this from Gnome. It would be reinstalling Ubuntu on a different version of LTS, correct?

Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @PauloBoaventura LTSes are released every two years and software versions are frozen for their lifetime. Downloading the same LTS version and installing it won't give you any updates anything that `apt upgrade` wouldn't install. (I believe HWE stack can be an exception from this rule, depending on your configuration).

Comment: This answers the question in the body of the post but not the question in the title

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 20.04 is an LTS release**. Therefore, you wouldn't expect a lot in Software changes as it is meant to be stable.

However you can be sure **Ubuntu 20.10** to be released on 22nd October will ship with GNOME 3.38.

If you really want to try out GNOME 3.38, [Download img file for GNOME 3.38 Beta (approx 2Gb)](https://gnome-build-meta.s3.amazonaws.com/3.37.92/gnome_os_installer.iso) From that Link and use it as a Virtual machine.

Comment: I have downloaded your link; - Its file name has no version number so I do not know what it is - Gnome-boxes crashes on startup. It ran for a day and the images of gnome-os I had yesterday will not load properly. - Including your link, I now have a total of three .iso files, all claiming to be Gnome-OS of some unspecified version, all different from each other, none will boot in a VM. - The images will boot on a Dell Laptop, but seem eager to install themselves onto "the hard disk", and I did not see an option to run them from the ISO image.